# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'user'

Tags: mysql

I am facing a problem in signing in mysql. I had mistaknely renamed user name from "root" to "xyz" and password as password.
Then onwards I couldnot run MySql from commandline using the root password which I set. Even can't proceed with the show database and table creation queries.
User shows  'root'@'localhost'  whereas current_user() is ''@'localhost'
I reinstalled MySql still the problem is there.

Please help me so that I can proceed with the mysql.

Thanks in advance,
Rajhrita

Answer (score 1):

Use the procedure at http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/recover-mysql-root-password.html to bypass security and recreate the password.